# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference in IE10

Tags: javascript

I have a js function which compares the value in the select object and the value saved in the function.

```
function xyz()
{
document.getElementById("max1").options.value='abc';
document.getElementById("max2").options.value='xyz';

    for (var i=0;i<=document.formabc.max1.options.length;i++)
    {   
       if(document.getElementById("max1").options[i].value == 
        document.getElementById("max1").options.value)
       {
          //Some code
       }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error that document.getElementById("max1").options[i] is undefined. I am using IE10. What can be a possible cause for the error.

Comment: Off-by-one error: `i <= document.formabc.max1.options.length` should be `i < document.formabc.max1.options.length`.

Comment: Thanks Frederic. Overlooked <= in for loop :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting this error when `i==0`? if not then change your `for` loop condition as

`for (var i=0; i < document.formabc.max1.options.length; i++)`

You have the condition as `i <= document.formabc.max1.options.length`.

If there are 10 items in the dropdown, 9th item will be the last, so loop needs to be continued upto 10 times (from 0 to 9 as zero based indexing). Based on your condition, the loop will continue upto 11 times (0 to 10) so you won't get `document.getElementById("max1").options[10].value`(which will be `undefined` as it doesnot exists).